# Remove specific string while writing log of .bat file

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I am creating a `.bat` file to transfer files from one server to another. After the file is moved, I delete the original `.bat` file. In addition to this I am writing log `.bat` file.

Code works fine, but the issue is along with result password being stored in the log file, I can't remove the same from original `.bat` file as this will be used for transferring to given credentials.

Can I remove the same from log file?
Below is my code for the same:

```
Shell("filters.bat >log.txt")
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are concerned about the password in the log file, yet you fail to be concerned about the password embedded within the log file. The cat's already out of the bag. You should re-evaluate your entire approach.

Comment: I have a typo in my prior comment. I meant to say *"..., yet you fail to be concerned about the password within the batch file."*

Comment: Just to add to what @dbenham has said, do not write the password to disk in plain text, ever. Not even for a short period of time. Depending on the type of disk/filesystem being used, replacing the file contents later might not overwrite the original, meaning the password is easily recoverable. Even if it does overwrite the same sectors, there are a dozen ways to intercept the password before you've got time to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to replace text (password with "***") in a text file (filename). It's untested, but should be close.

```
s = system.io.file.readalltext(filename)
s = s.replace(password, "****")
system.io.file.writealltext(filename, s)
```

To replace it while writing the file, just use the string replace on whatever string you're writing:

```
s = system.io.file.readalltext(batchoutput)
s = s.replace(password, "****")
system.io.file.appendalltext(logfilename, s)
```

Comment: Hello.. thanks for your feedback. Basically log file will be used by I.T. team while password is belonging to user who is using the.exe.

Comment: Modifying the log  file will be alternate solution but not first. This is because we can easily track file before it is modified

Answer (score 0):

Issue got solved by  echo off line in the batch file creatation before password is being entered.